# trying to filter an array

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
console.log(this.productlist[this.productlist.length-1] === product); //says: true
this.productlist == this.productlist.filter(p => p !== product);
console.log(this.productlist);  //the product is still in the list
```

I want to filter the `product`(which is the last item in the list) out of `this.productlist`. The first console.log says true, so both objects are the same. But the second console.log shows that the product is still in the list.

I use the filter on other places and there it works. I am clueless. What can I do to find out why this is not working here?

Comment: You are using a `==` equality operator, not the assignment `=`.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @SachinGupta

Comment: @SachinGupta Oh thank you so much! I was looking at that code for so long but I just not seen the double `=`....

Comment: @nbar posted it as an answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 2, you are using a `==` equality operator, not the assignment `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Various methods to remove last item from array:

Use filter:

`array = array.filter((elem,index) => index != array.length-1)`

using splice:

`array.splice(array.length-1)`

using slice:

`array.slice(0,array.length-1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically after the last element you can use pop.

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4]
let b = a.pop()
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```